# Optional Field validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am having some problem in JavaScript form validation.

I have some optional fields in my HTML code. On submit, they don't need to be filled up but if the user provides some input they must be verified. For instance, I have an optional phone number field. If the user provides an input then I need to check if they are all numbers.

How could I do that?

Comment: http://html5pattern.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need only invoke the validation code if the field value meets some precondition, in this case: if the field has a value (checked by testing the `length` property of the string value):

```
var fieldValue = document.getElementById("someInput").value;
if( fieldValue.length > 0 ) {

    if( someValidationFunction( fieldValue ) ) alert("Field is invalid");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's stopping you from using HTML5's own validation?

```
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]+" />
```

No JavaScript required, will work on all modern browsers.

---

A note on security: Please don't rely on client-side validations for security concerns, as they can be trivially disabled. All validation should *also* be done server-side.

Answer (score 0):

you can bind your custom method as a callback to your submit action in your form

```
<form onSubmit="return customValidation()>
```

In the method do your validations.

```
function customValidation()
{    
    //code to test fields
    fieldToValidate = document.getElementById("field-id")
    //validate the field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the other answers if you need it to be more secure; you shouldn't do this with JavaScript, because if a user for some reason has it turned off in their browser (or they turned it off on purpose) then the form won't still be verified. Instead you need to do it with PHP on the server. On the server that the form is being sent to you need to get the query strings sent with the form (`$_GET['phonenumber'];`), and see if it's a number (`int intval ( mixed $phonenumber )`). This should return NaN if it's not a number.